# How to save SVG in internal Storage And retrieve it and set it to ImageView?

Tags: android, svg

I need to save the .svg in the Internal storage of android application and retrieve it and set it to the ImageView.

I am not able to save the .svg file. i am using this method -

```
 File cacheDir = ctx.getCacheDir();
            f = new File(cacheDir, name + ".png");

            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageurl).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                try {

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                            f);
                    mIcon.compress(
                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                            100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                    return f;

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    return null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Just FYI you can convert SVG to XML using New import svg option available in Android Studio if you are not explicitly looking someway to store   in device storage. This URL might help in importing svg to Android studio https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Comment: I intend to do it programmatically. I am load the svg from server and save it to the internal storage and show it in a imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you decoding SVG into bitmap ? I'm not sure it is possible.

But if you want to save the SVG file to storage, just copy you input stream to the output stream.

Simple java solution :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

or [with IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream))

If you want to display your SVG file, look at https://github.com/pents90/svg-android/tree/master/svgandroid